# How to easily switch between Skyrim and Something to take notes on?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like to play Skyrim, pause the game and switch to a program to take notes on. Any suggestions?

Comment: A pen and a notepad?

Comment: Skyrim does *not* handle alt-tabbing gracefully. At all. Though, there are some mods out there, like [Take Notes - Journal of the Dragonborn](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/48375/?) that let you take notes within the game. I've not tried that particular mod, however, anything that's featured on G.E.M.S. is usually good.

Comment: Save Take Notes from game to computer drive?

Comment: @linuxfreebird According to the info page, it's saved to `/Skyrim/Data/SKSE/Plugins/FISS/TakeNotes/JournalExport.txt`, usually.

Comment: I'd like to echo what @Doozer said - while it may take a while to set up, the reward is definitely worth it.

Answer (score 16):

I have used a web based editor in the browser within the steam overlay for this.  You could use something like gist, evernote, [markable](http://markable.in/editor/).

Press shift tab to bring up the overlay.

Comment: *facepalm* I forgot about the Steam Overlay being a thing that doesn't crash the game >_>

Answer (score 1):

Skyrim doesn't handle switching between applications very well. At all. Roughly 50% of my alt-tab attempts with Skyrim end in a crash to desktop. You *could* switch out of Skyrim with alt-tab (or similar key combo, depending on your operating system), but I don't really recommend it.

If you're not too afraid of mods, you could use [Take Notes - Journal of the Dragonborn](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/48375/). It adds an in-game journal which could be used to take notes within the game. It also allows you to export your journal entries to a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Play in windowed mode.  After starting Skyrim, go to options and enable the windowed mode setting.  The windowed mode plays **much** better with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> compared to playing fullscreen.

Unfortunately, you will now have a non-borderless window decorated with the Skyrim titlebar and the max/min/close buttons of a normal Windows' window.  I have yet to find a way to launch in borderless window mode without mods.

Comment: There are many solutions for borderless windowed mode, OneTweak being my favorite.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a tablet while you play?

Thats what I do

Comment: Or smartphone... or just a pen(cil)+paper.

Answer (score 0):

[Overwolf](http://www.overwolf.com/) is an overlay system similar to steam but offers a number of addons including a notepad that i use for the similar purpose, when playing some games.